# GetEntity from Generic DataRepository not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, generics, repository

I am trying to create a generic repository with the basic CRUD operations. I am having trouble with my GetEntity function

```
protected override T GetEntity(FinancialDataContext entityContext, int id)
{
    var query = (from e in entityContext.Set<T>()
                 where e.Id == id
                 select e);
    var result = query.FirstOrDefault();
    return result;
}
```

**The error is at my e."Id" and says "T does not contain a definition for 'Id' and no extension method 'Id' accepting a first argument of type 'T' could be found ( missing reference?)**

How do I reference the 'promise' of an Id? or is there another way around this?

Comment: Consider introducing some common abstract class, say `BaseEntity` for all your entities, which defines Id property. Then T can be declared as `where T : BaseEntity`

Comment: Im not sure what you mean @Andrei...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have some level of control on how your entities are declared, here is what you can do. Create a base class which declares the `Id` property:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    public in Id { get; set; }
}
```

Then make all your entities inherit this class (make sure to remove Id declaration from them as it is already in a base class):

```
public class Entity1 : BaseEntity
```

Now in your generic repository you can actually put some constraint on how it can be typed:

```
public class Repository<T> where T : BaseEntity
```

This is good on its own, but it also gives you access to `Id` (and whatever other common properties this `BaseEntity` might have).

Comment: the id property is created with the entity framework. This is what I needed, thanks!!